# Bootstrap 4 strange margin under images

Tags: margin, padding

I am getting a strange margin under my images.
I have set the margin/padding on both the containing div and the image to 0

This is the site i'm working on: https://www.philipnordstrom.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is coming from your body font-size: 10px. If you change it to 1px the space between is gone. Try to add a css class like: div a { font-size: 0; }

Answer (score 0):

You can see the link on the picture. I cannot tell you why this happens maybe because images aren't meant to be linked like this in the default case. I would need to dig deeper inside this to tell you the reason ;)

[image]